# Algorithm for organizing an schedule depending of the time of some events?

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, search, data-structures

I want to make a program that each semester, creates a schedule depending of a list of classes I input, so if I add various classes, depending of the time and days that these classes will happen then the program would be able to match what classes can be added without intercepting each other. I want to know if there is an algorithms or way of comparing the class schedule in order to determine what classes can I have from the list of courses.

The only way of doing these that I can imagine is with many if statements or adding an starting course and then having an array that tracks the hours, starting each position at 0 and then each time an hour is occupied I change the array position to 1. Then when adding a course I check what positions are different to 1 and try to add the class.

I want to find a more optimal solution to this problem than the ones I can imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a planning problem. Planning problem are very difficult to solve in a efficient way: performance issues arise very quickly in this kind of problem.

If you just want to solve the problem, you should check an existing planning problem solver like [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/): it's open source, so you can try to understand how it work and there is a [blog](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/) with interresting thoughts about planning problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting a method where, given a group of classes with their times and a chosen class, output the available classes, you can use simple iteration to do the job. Suppose you have a 5 hour slot with 4 classes you could represent each class with a single array:

```
int[][] times = {
            {0,1,1,0,0},
            {1,1,0,0,0},
            {0,1,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,1,1}
    };
```

So if you were to choose the class taking up the last 2hrs then the remaining options would be:

```
{0,1,1,0,0},
{1,1,0,0,0},
{0,1,0,0,0}
```

Given this representation you could do something like:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class C {

    static int[][] available(int[] c,int[][] times){
        ArrayList<Integer> index = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
            if(c[i]==1) index.add(i);

        for(int i = 0; i < times.length; i++){
            if(!times[i].equals(c)) {
                for (int j = 0; j < times[0].length; j++) {
                    if(times[i][j]==1){
                        if(index.contains(j)) break;
                    }
                    if(j==times[0].length-1) result.add(i);
                }
            }
        }
        int[][] r = new int[result.size()][c.length];
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            r[i] = times[result.get(i)];
        }
        return r;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        int[][] times = {
                {0,1,1,0,0},
                {1,1,0,0,0},
                {0,1,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,1,1}
        };
        int[] c =  {0,0,0,1,1};
        available(c,times);

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(available(c,times)));


    }

}
```